# Recurrence of number of derangement of $[n]$ with $k$ cycles

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs, derangements

Let $d(n,k)$ be the number of derangement of $[n]$ with $k$ cycles. Derive a recurrence for $d(n,k)$.

I know the formula for $d(n,k)$(which involves unsigned Stirling number of the first kid) but I am not sure how to derive a recurrence combinatorially for $d(n,k)$

Update:
I have tried to derive a recurrence for $d(n,k)$ but not sure if it is right or not. Any help/ advice/ correction would be appreciated.

Here is my attempt:
We count the ways to partition $[n]$ into $k$ cycles of length at least $2$. There are two cases:

1st Case: If the cycle containing the element $n$ has length $2$, then there are $n-1$ ways to pick its other element, and there are $d(n-2,k-1)$ ways to derange the remaining $n-2$ elements into $k-1$ cycles.

2nd Case: If the cycle containing the element $n$ has length $\geq$3, then skipping element $n$ in its cycle still leaves cycle of length at least $2$, and we can produce a derangement of $[n-1]$ into $k$ cycles, which gives us $d(n-1, k)$ ways. On the other hand, every derangement of $[n]$ with $n$ into $k$ cycles arises from a derangement of $[n-1]$ of $k$ cycle by inserting $n$ immediately following some $x\in[n-1]$ on the cycle containing $x$. So, there are $(n-1)d(n-1,k)$ of this type.

So, the derived recurrence is $d(n,k)= (n-1)(d(n-2,k-1)+ d(n-1,k))$

Any help/ advice/ correction would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know $d(n-1,k)$ how many ways are there to add $n$ to it to make a derangement on $[n]$?  What derangements on $[n]$ with $k$ cycles cannot be constructed this way?

Comment: @Ross Millikan for the first question: is it $(n-1)$ ways? And I have no idea about the second question

Comment: @Ross Millikan I have tried to derive a recurrence for $d(n,k)$ but not sure if it is right or not. I got $d(n,k) = (n-1)(d(n-2,k-1) + d(n-1,k))$

Comment: You should edit that into your question along with the logic you used to derive it.  The second term is the answer to my first question, so the first should be the answer to my second.

Comment: @RossMillikan i have edited that into my question, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your analysis is spot-on, and is confirmed by https://oeis.org/A008306

Comment: I agree with Mike Earnest.  No advice needed.